# Setting up a python dev environment using Docker (with linting and code completion in vscode)

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

## Setup

I'm exploring the ways of setting up a python dev environment inside a docker container.

In my local (host) I have the project directory:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── foo.py
```

Where my `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:latest

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install matplotlib

RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
```

and the script is:

```
try:
    import matplotlib
    print("import successfully")
except ImportError:
    print("unable to import matplotlib")
```

Assuming I don't have `matplotlib` installed on my host, then `python foo.py` yields `unable to import matplotlib`. When I run inside the container:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ~/tmp/:/src/ py-deb-test foo.py
```

I get `import successfully`.

## Problem

Now, my intention is to work on my code using vscode on the local host and run it in the container. The problem is that in this setting I don't know how to point vscode to the python "installation" running in the container. I thought of starting the container and "mounting" the python from the container to a local location and point vscode to this location. But so far it didn't work.

Without solving this, vscode is not aware of what packages are installed, where to find the linter, etc...

Any help and ideas would be welcome!

Comment: I assume you're running python script through some package for vs code like [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)?

Comment: No. I indicated that I either run it directly from my host terminal or using `docker run`.

Comment: VScode released [Remote Development extension pack](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) which seems to address this very issue. I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Good news. The folks at VScode recently released what seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Using the [containers remote VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) it is now possible to run the editor on a container which has the exact environment that one needs. In [this repo](https://github.com/drorata/vscode-remote-python-ml/tree/900eaf006b44b673ec920554f233313ee5e9f13e) I compiled a minimal example and I hope you'd find it useful.

Comment: This was so so so helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any official support for this scenario right now, but you can follow the [issue tracking remote interpreter support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/79) to know when we do have some solution.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still interesting for someone:

I've set up a docker container with Python, R and Latex and code-completion, linting and compilation for those languages. A VS-Code devcontainer file is also provided which sets the settings to sensible defaults (especially path variables so that the devcontainer finds the executables when running).

You can find it [here](https://github.com/BerriJ/devenv).